# How to run a Bash shell script via Win32 CreateProcess through Wine?

Tags: macos, bash, winapi, wine

I'm trying to make a Win32 program work on Mac through WINE.
This program used to call another Win32 program as an external process using CreateProcess() API.
I now want it to call a UNIX shell script on Mac through WINE.

I succeeded in creating a process that runs a straightforward command: `/usr/bin/touch /Users/username/Desktop/file`

```
CreateProcess( NULL, const_cast<LPWSTR>( (LPCWSTR) _T("/usr/bin/touch /Users/username/Desktop/file")  ), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
            NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi );
```

However, I tried to replace the command using `/bin/sh /Users/username/Desktop/my.sh`
This time it failed.

At first I thought it was due to path issue, I thought WINE would use Windows path. So I tried to load ntdll.dll, then use the API wine_unix_to_nt_file_name() to convert the script path to a WINE-flavor Windows path. It still does not work (my.script just calls the the same `touch` command listed above).

I wonder if my goal was misguided. Is it possible to achieve what I wanted with WINE?

Comment: Have you tried turning on [debugging output](http://www.winehq.org/docs/winedev-guide/dbg-control) for Wine to see if it tells you something usable?